# Chrome extension content_script isolation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have two scripts that operate on the **same domain** as per:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["https://myurl.com/*"],
    "js": ["do_stuff.js"]
  },
  {
    "matches": ["https://myurl.com/*"],
    "js": ["do_other_stuff.js"]
  }
],
```

In both files I start with creating a var of the same name:

```
let myvar = "foo";
```

However, one of the scripts will then throw an error claiming the var has already been defined. (I also get peculiar results when function names are the same between scripts).

My understanding from the Google documentation is that each content_script is explicitly sandboxed from each other and so wouldn't have access to each others variables.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

The page says a content script **cannot** "Use variables or functions defined by web pages or by other content scripts".

What am I doing wrong and/or misunderstanding?

Comment: "Other" means other extensions. All your content scripts for a given page run in the same sandbox.

Comment: It occurred to me that my word and your own experience aren't enough so here's the [source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/extensions/renderer/script_injection.cc?l=49): as you can see there's only one isolated world per each injection host (extension) in a given frame (page or iframe). You're probably the first one who noticed the ambiguity of that phrase. Consider suggesting the developers to improve the documentation.

Comment: Thankyou! It appears to my (rusty) c++ reading that they are indeed creating isolated worlds per frame per *hosturl*, which would explain my issues. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Did you think that the sandboxing was one sandbox per entry in `content_scripts` (i.e. 1 sandbox per `"js"` list, but shared within each list)? Because, the first example on the [content scripts page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) shows loading *jquery.js* along with *myscript.js*. Loading a library like jQuery would be useless if the content scripts did not share the sandbox.

Comment: In that example Jquery and myscript.js are both loaded within the same content_script entry, so I would expect them to share the same sandbox. I would not, however, expect them to share the same sandbox as a separate content_script entry - as per my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, the comments by https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom above identified and solved the issue - basically, that the documentation (at least at the time) was a bit ambiguously worded, and the execution environments are actually sandboxed by frame and hosturl, and not by content script definition.